# Local path in TFS dialog either defaults uneditable to different folder or can't connect in Windows 10

Tags: tfs, robohelp

I was running TFS MSSCCI Provider v11 to integrate with RoboHelp 10 on Windows 7. I would open an RH project by selecting the TFS version control option, which would eventually open the Choose Folder in Team Foundation Server dialog. Then I would drill down to the relevant project folder on the server side. When I selected a folder, the proper Local Path was populated (as defined in the workspace via VS Team Explorer (2013)).

Now in Windows 10, I have two major problems:

- I can map a local path with Source Control Explorer, but then when I try to open a RH project by selecting a folder, the Local Path is empty so I have to type or browse to the path. When I click OK, it says the path is already mapped in the workspace.
- If I don't map the folder with Source Control Explorer beforehand, I can manually assign a local path and successfully open a RH project with a TFS connection. When I check out a file in RH, it is shown as locked in Source Control Explorer but the red check symbol is not there, and of course the local path remains Not mapped. And if I try to map it, it is "already mapped." So essentially, the two components are out of sync.

[Choose Folder in TFS dialog, proper local path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC21m.gif)

But in this case, no folders are mapped in Source Control.

The other problem is that in other cases when I map a folder with Source Control Explorer and open a project with RH, the Local Path either defaults to C:\ or C:\WINDOWS\system32 instead of what I defined in the workspace. Plus this path is uneditable. However, it also creates a new workspace with a _1 extension to my existing workspace, in which I can edit the path, but I don't want an extra workspace.

[Choose Folder in TFS dialog, fixed local path, multiple workspaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5v4j.gif)

So how do I get the Visual Studio interface and RoboHelp back in synch?

Thank you.

Comment: So the issue occurs on Win10 and does not occur on Win7?

Comment: Eddie,

Yes, the behavior in Windows 7 is fine. The other strange thing is that there is a dialog in RoboHelp that asks for the version control provider. TFS is one option and there is a default RoboHelp SharePoint Connector option. There is a "Make this my default selection" check box also but it is not editable as it is in Win 7.